# Error while running anything with manage.py in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I created a Django project the previous month and I deleted it. But now whenever I create a Django project and run any command with manage.py, it gives me an error regarding the previously deleted project.
E.g: When I ran python manage.py makemigrations, it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 423, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\translation.py", line 43, in check_setting_languages
    for tag, _ in settings.LANGUAGES if not isinstance(tag, str) or not language_code_re.match(tag)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\django\\car_service\\car_service\\settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line     
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 367, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 208, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 144, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\django\\car_service\\car_service\\settings'
```

Here car_service is the name of the deleted project.

Here is my settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for music_app project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'music_app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'music_app.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: Are you in the right working directory for your new project?

Comment: The project name is music app but you're in car_service directory. Assuming you haven't named your project one and your directory another, I think you're running the project from the wrong directory

Comment: Yes, I am in the current project directory with manage.py file.